# What JRE home to set in Eclipse for JDK7u4 on Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, java, java-7

I downloaded JDK7u4 for Mac OS X, and installed it.
Now I would like to setup Eclipse to use this JDK. In `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` what location should I set for JRE home? I installed it on the default location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Oracles's JDK release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-for-mac-readme-1564562.html#eclipse)

> In the "JRE Home:" field, type "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home"

Note you will have to type it as the open dialog finds a OSX bundle at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/ and will not browse into it

Answer (score 2):

See this? 
http://code.google.com/p/openjdk-osx-build/wiki/EclipseWithOpenJDK

Home dir would be: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/